# azure mobile backend slow down

Tags: c#, azure, backend, restful-architecture

This is more an architecture question than programming. I noticed a couple of days ago a slow down on my app http requests. I started looking around and there was not obvious error so I restarted the web service.

The restart fixed the slow down instantly, than I came to the conclusion that my backend might have been overwhelm by multiple requests at the same time. (My app users uploaded a good bit of photos all day long).

My question is this:
Do Azure mobile backends have a hard limit on stream connections (like 10 people streaming a photo upload) and if so how should I deal with it? I have activated the 3 instances feature on my app web service, but I see little difference as to how my backend works.

Any insight into this would be a really big help.

---

Little insight into this issues. The memory set seems to have jumped by 100Mb in seconds... (as recorded when the slow down occurred) I believe this to be related to the creation of thumbnails and timestamped of the uploaded images. (images are saved into a blob). will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware if there are any streaming connections limits, but there are limits for sure, some of which listed [there](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/).

Regarding your issue, i would split it to the two parts:

1) Diagnostics and troubleshooting. Here, it is really difficult to say why it happens without the profiling of what is going on with your application. Azure Web Apps provide a lot of troubleshooting capabilities, Application Insights included, so you could be able to identify what is the issue. [Troubleshoot: performance degradation in a web app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation/) and [that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-monitor-performance/), for example.

2) Architecture. What concerns me is where you put your photos. The uploading feature is very common and easy, and the issues mean that probably there is something wrong with the code. Did you see that [guidance on how to use Mobile Services to upload the images](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-upload-data-blob-storage/)?

Comment: The uploading works this way: 1. A stream is open to the service. 2. The picture is uploaded and a thumbnail created as well as timestamped. 3. both the original and the thumbnail picture get moved to a blob in Azure. ; I will update the question as soon as I get time to further investigate this issue.

Comment: Did you consider to offload some tasks to something like work ticket pattern? When front end put the image to the blob gets the link for that, send the link as the message to the queue and some workers can get and generate the thumbnail and do other work? Or I think you could leverage the WebJob functionality here - we use that and front end asks webjob to make the processing

Comment: I can actually see where it all went downhill. I am loading the photos into memory where they are process so I am guessing that came back to bite me. If I use your method I would guess I will have to keep track of the job list somehow and just notify the server that a new photo has been added. Yes something like this will work.

Comment: @ScarletMerlin that is how i would do that as memory is the bottleneck that may be difficult to overcome (especially in the cloud, where you may have some noisy neighborhood). If that may be the answer, please mark the question answered for a future reference.